# Optional chaining with Swift strings

Tags: swift, string, option-type

With optional chaining, if I have a Swift variable

```
var s: String?
```

s might contain nil, or a String wrapped in an Optional. So, I tried this to get its length:

```
let count = s?.characters?.count ?? 0
```

However, the compiler wants this:

```
let count = s?.characters.count ?? 0
```

My understanding of optional chaining is that, once you start using `?.` in a dotted expression, the rest of the properties are made optional and are typically accessed by `?.`, not `.`.

So, I dug a little further and tried this in the playground:

```
var s: String? = "Foo"
print(s?.characters)
// Output: Optional(Swift.String.CharacterView(_core: Swift._StringCore(_baseAddress: 0x00000001145e893f, _countAndFlags: 3, _owner: nil)))
```

The result indicates that `s?.characters` is indeed an Optional instance, indicating that `s?.characters.count` should be illegal.

Can someone help me understand this state of affairs?

Comment: Both `s?.characters.count` and `(s?.characters)?.count` compile, but `(s?.characters).count` doesn't. It looks like `characters.count` is treated like a single optional chaining in the first case, but I haven't seen that documented.

Comment: Now also discussed on [swift-users]: https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-users/Week-of-Mon-20160801/002764.html.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you say:

> My understanding of optional chaining is that, once you start using `?.` in a dotted expression, the rest of the properties are made optional and are typically accessed by `?.`, not `.`.

I would say that you are almost there.

It’s not that all the properties are made optional, it’s that the original call is optional, so it looks like the other properties are optional.

`characters` is not an optional property, and neither is `count`, but the value that you are calling it on is optional. If there is a value, then the `characters` and `count` properties will return a value; otherwise, `nil` is returned. It is because of this that the result of `s?.characters.count` returns an `Int?`.

If either of the properties were optional, then you would need to add `?` to it, but, in your case, they aren’t. So you don’t.

---

**Edited following comment**

From the comment:

> I still find it strange that both `s?.characters.count` and `(s?.characters)?.count` compile, but `(s?.characters).count` doesn't. Why is there a difference between the first and the last expression?

I’ll try and answer it here, where there is more room than in the comment field:

```
s?.characters.count
```

If `s` is nil, the whole expression returns `nil`, otherwise an `Int`. So the return type is `Int?`.

```
(s?.characters).count // Won’t compile
```

Breaking this down: if `s` is `nil`, then `(s?.characters)` is `nil`, so we can’t call `count` on it.

In order to call the `count` property on `(s?.characters)`, the expression needs to be optionally unwrapped, i.e. written as:

```
(s?.characters)?.count
```

---

**Edited to add further**

The best I can get to explaining this is with this bit of playground code:

```
let s: String? = "hello"

s?.characters.count
(s?.characters)?.count
(s)?.characters.count
((s)?.characters)?.count

// s?.characters.count
func method1(s: String?) -> Int? {
    guard let s = s else { return nil }

    return s.characters.count
}

// (s?.characters).count
func method2(s: String?) -> Int? {
    guard let c = s?.characters else { return nil }

    return c.count
}

method1(s)
method2(s)
```

Comment: I still find it strange that both `s?.characters.count` and `(s?.characters)?.count` compile, but `(s?.characters).count` doesn't. Why is there a difference between the first and the last expression?

Comment: In `(s?.characters).count` you try to get the `count` property of an optional. In the first one `characters` is not an optional.

Comment: @MartinR I've tried to answer this in the edited answer.

Comment: But wouldn't the same argument apply in the first expression? `s?.characters` has the type `Int?` (and is `nil` if `s == nil`). Why can we call `count` on it in `s?.characters.count`? Why does adding parentheses make a difference?

Comment: It's the `s` that has the optional type. Once it's successfully unwrapped, you can chain all the other calls on to the non-optional value. So you are calling `characters.count` on a `String` if it exists, or just returning `nil` if it does not. when you wrap in parentheses, you are evaluating the parentheses before calling the outside methods on it. so rather than calling `characters.count` on the unwrapped value, you are calling `characters` on an optional String (which is an Optional) and then calling count on the result  which has to be conditionally unwrapped.

Comment: But in both cases, `characters` is called on the string and then `count` on the result. There is no `characters.count` property which you can call on the string.

Comment: Without the parentheses, `characters.count` is called on the unwrapped value. With the parentheses `s?.characters` is evaluated first and then `count`. Since `s?.characters` as an expression is optional, this has to be unwrapped before calling `count` on it.

Comment: But there is no `characters.count` property! It seems that the compiler *treats* it as a "combined property", but it would be nice to have a definite reference for that. – Why should there be a difference between `a.b.c` , `(a.b).c` or `((a).b).c)`?

Comment: Your answer is (as I understand it) supported on swift-users: https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-users/Week-of-Mon-20160801/002768.html :)

Comment: Good to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

On the Swift-users mailing list, Ingo Maier was kind enough to point me to the [section on optional chaining expressions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/optional-chaining-expression) in the Swift language spec, which states:

> If a postfix expression that contains an optional-chaining expression is nested inside other postfix expressions, only the outermost expression returns an optional type.

It continues with the example:

```
var c: SomeClass?
var result: Bool? = c?.property.performAction()
```

This explains why the compiler wants **s?.characters.count** in my example above, and I consider that it answers the original question. However, as @Martin R observed in a comment, there is still a mystery as to why these two expressions are treated differently by the compiler:

```
s?.characters.count
(s?.characters).count
```

If I am reading the spec properly, the subexpression

```
(s?.characters)
```

is "nested inside" the overall postfix expression

```
(s?.characters).count
```

and thus should be treated the same as the non-parenthesized version. But that's a separate issue.

Thanks to all for the contributions!

Comment: As discussed on the list, the spec is a bit lacking about the scope of the question mark, but I think that swiftc does the right thing. It is fairly common in programming languages to use parentheses to delimit the scope of all kinds of operators/keywords. It often leads to the nice (I would say intuitive) property that you can replace parenthesized expressions with let bindings and still have the same semantics. Using your example, `let x = s?.characters; x?.count` has the same semantics as `(s?.characters)?.count` which would not be the case if `(s?.characters).count` was valid Swift code.