# Why can't I call map<U>(_ transform: (Wrapped) -> U) -> U? and use optional chaining at the same time?

Tags: swift, option-type, optional-chaining

I know that optional chaining like this:

```
someOptional?.someProperty
```

is basically

```
someOptional.map { $0.someProperty }
```

However, I found that doing both at the same time is not possible:

```
// someOptional?.someProperty evaluates to an optional type, right?
// so the map method should exist!
someOptional?.someProperty.map(someClosure) // can't find "map"
```

Here's an MCVE:

```
let s: String? = "Hello"
s?.hashValue.map(Double.init)
```

I think writing something like the above is more readable than:

```
s.map { Double($0.hashValue) }
```

So I would really like a way to use optional chaining and `map` at the same time.

How do I do this?

Comment: Closely related: [Optional chaining with Swift strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38699734/optional-chaining-with-swift-strings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, for some reason, wrapping the first part in brackets worked:

```
(s?.hashValue).map(Double.init)
```

I think this is somehow due to the `?` having a lower precedence, or that optional chaining doesn't work the same way as other expressions. Adding the brackets might have caused `s?.hashValue` to become an expression.

Edit:

Here is the relevant excerpt from the [Swift reference](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Expressions.html#//appleref/swift/grammar/optional-chaining-expression):

> If a postfix expression that contains an optional-chaining expression
>   is nested inside other postfix expressions, only the outermost
>   expression returns an optional type. In the example below, when c is
>   not nil, its value is unwrapped and used to evaluate .property, the
>   value of which is used to evaluate .performAction(). The entire
>   expression c?.property.performAction() has a value of an optional
>   type.

So `s?.hashValue` doesn't actually evaluate to an optional type, because it is nested inside another expression. By adding `()`, I separated it into another expression, manually making it evaluate to an optional type.